# How can I compare numbers fetched from a database with sqlite3 in Python?

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tuples

I'm quite new at programming, and I'm working in python with sqlite3, and I have a column where the numbers are ordered, but there might be gaps (1, 2, 4, 7, 8...). What I'm trying to do is to make a For loop, in which I compare the numbers in order (IDs), and eliminate the gaps (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...).

The function goes

```
def deleteGaps(idTuple):

    idList = list(idTuple) #converting the fetched Tuple to a List to be able to modify it
    previousId=-1 # -1 because the first element is [0]

    for id in idList:     
        if id > previousId+1:
           id = previousId+1
           print(id) #Just for testing, later I'll work on the side of updating the table

    previousId = id
```

And it gives me the following error

```
    if id > previousId+1:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

If I go print(idList), it gives me "[(1,), (2,), (4,), (7,), (8,)]" instead of the expected "(1, 2, 4, 7, 8)". That's likely the root of the problem, but I don't know how to make the conversion correctly.

Any suggestions? Thanks y'all.

PS: I realize that I can just get the length of the tuple and assign 1, 2, 3... to n=lenght, but I'd like to know how to go from [(1,), (2,)] to (1, 2) anyways.

Comment: Some remarks: `id` is the name of a built-in function, don't use it for something else. Modifying the loop variable within the loop is not recommended in any language I know of. Your print statement seems to have wrong indentation. Take a look at the `enumerate` function instead of trying to emulate it with `previousId`.

Comment: Thanks I'll avoid using "id".  In this kind of loop, modifying the loop variable didn't seem to do anything in the list unless I saved the change with "givenList[i]" (being "i" a variable used as a counter). I'll take a look to enumerate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code ıd is tuple but you are comparing with int.  `id = int(id) if id > previousId+1: id = previousId+1`

can you try this

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for the PS part:

```
flattened_tuple = tuple(x[0] for x in ((1,), (2,), (3,)))
```

yields `(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what you're trying to make, but I can fix your bug:

that's because `id` is of type `tuple` and you can't apply add operation `+` between
`tuple` and `int`
You need to access the values inside your tuple, so try to:

```
def deleteGaps(idTuple):

    idList = list(idTuple) #converting the fetched Tuple to a List to be able to modify it
    previousId=-1 # -1 because the first element is [0]

    for id in idList:
        id = id[0] # using `[0]` means that you're accessing the tuple's first value
        if id > previousId+1:
           id = previousId+1
           print(id) #Just for testing, later I'll work on the side of updating the table

    previousId = id
```

note: `id` is of type `tuple` *to simplify it*, because the result from sqlite3 query is a `tuple`

if you don't want to use `[0]` and sense this `tuple` is always looks like `(value,)`, then you can do following:

```
    for id, _ in idList:
        if id > previousId+1:
           id = previousId+1
           print(id) #Just for testing, later I'll work on the side of updating the table

    previousId = id
```